# Why does html POST take me to an unexpected page?

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a simple web application built with Python using flask that has three pages: main, index, and post. I am trying to get to the "if request.method == "POST"" section of the index page. To test this I've asked it to render the post.html page. For some reason when I send a POST method from the index page I'm instead being redirected to my main_page. The python code looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("main_page.html")
    #implied ELSE here (if it's not GET, do the following for a POST)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new_index():
    if request.method == "POST":

        #I AM TRYING TO GET HERE 

        return render_template('post.html')
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('index.html',)

@app.route('/post')
def post():
    return render_template('post.html')
```

The POST method from index.html comes from this:

```
<div class="row">
    <form role="form" method='POST' action='.'>
      <textarea class="form-control" name="contents" placeholder="Enter a comment"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I'm not particularly familiar with HTML but I've tried everything I can think of. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to link to the same page in a form action you should actually put a question mark, an empty string, a hash or just leave out the attribute all together. Doing either of these will fix your code.

```
<form role="form" method='POST' action='?'>
<form role="form" method='POST' action='#'>
<form role="form" method='POST' action=''>
<form role="form" method='POST'>
```

My personal preference is using.

```
<form role="form" method='POST' action='#'>
```

This will validate in XHTML and doesn't open up any known attack vectors.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I did was testing your API using Postman, and that all works fine: GET goes to the GET handler, POST goes to the POST handler.

The error I found is in the html form, in particular the **action** tag: you should point that to the API handler explicitly, and relative to the hostname. So, for example, setting that to:

```
<form role="form" method='POST' action='/index'>
```

will actually perform a POST on the **/index** API of your Flask app.

Comment: This is in general not a very maintainable way to do this. You should just make the action the current page so if you change the name of your webpage then it won't affect your code.

Comment: @Jamie C I don't agree on this. I think having the explicit URI/API endpoint in the form makes it more readable and easier to maintain in the long term. The '?' option is a shortcut, but also changes the URI to which you are sent. Now, your 'GET' comes from '/index' and a POST sends you to '/index?', which is not exactly the same thing.